# check attribute is not undefined jQuery in <tr>

Tags: jquery

I want to retrieve attribute values of all rows present in my table.and i some how done that but the starting & ending values comes as "undefined".

how to apply validation on that.i tried some code but doesnt seem to be work.

```
function currentTicketStatus() {
    var ids;
    $('tbody tr').each(function() {
        ids += ((ids == '' && ids !== 'undefined') ? '' : '|') + $(this).attr('title');
    });
    alert(ids);
}
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle of that

Comment: the condition should be `((ids == '' && ids !== undefined) ? '' : ids + '|') `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
var ids = '';

$('tbody tr[title]').each(function() {
      ids+=$(this).attr('title') + '|';
});
alert(ids);
```

or you can try this

```
var ids = [];

$('tbody tr[title]').each(function() {
      ids.push($(this).attr('title'));
});
alert(ids.join('|'));
```

Comment: first value undefined then proper

Comment: @ ^ Now all undefined values printing..:(

Comment: @SagarDumbre, now try this, it will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` method:

```
titles = $('tbody tr[title]').map(function() {
            return this.title
         }).get()

console.log(titles.join('|'))
```

Comment: in alert it prints [object Object]

Comment: @SagarDumbre use `console.log(ids)`

Comment: @SagarDumbre Do your tr elements have id attributes?

Comment: tr has only 'title' & 'class' and i want to retrieve 'title'

Comment: Now it prints "no title attribute","no title attribute",100,101,"no title attribute"

Comment: @SagarDumbre So it means that some of your rt elements have no title attributes, do you wanna skip those that don't have title attributes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16130/discussion-between-sagar-dumbre-and-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

this will do your work

```
   var ids = '';
   $('tbody tr').each(function() {
   if($(this).attr('title')!='undefined' && $(this).attr('title')!='')
   {
      ids+=$(this).attr('title') + '|';
   }
   });
   alert(ids);
```

Comment: 90% Done...But now it starts with SINGLE undefined value then all title values

Comment: first undefined and last two undefined :(

Comment: @SagarDumbre working for me here http://jsfiddle.net/6TvS4/ if this is not your html looks like please provide your html